# Unity logging not appearing in Adb

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, adb

I'm running an android dev build with the following:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UniRx;
using EasyMobile;
using System;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("Test");
        print("Test");
    }
}
```

Running in dev mode on Android adb logcat never shows 'Test'.

It does however show exceptions in the logs (such as null reference exceptions) which makes me t hink there's something being lost in the Debug.Log

Comment: Are you getting any other debug.logs showing up? if not it may be that you're not logging all logigng levels (maybe only errors/warnings). Try running this in your adb: `adb logcat -s Unity ActivityManager PackageManager dalvikvm DEBUG ` this should log everything

Comment: no logs at all, if I do a plain adb logcat I get logging for everything else oging on in the phone but not for my unity app unless the app is throwing exceptions. So weird.

Comment: can you see logs of Debug.LogWarning or Debug.LogError?

Comment: I dont believe debug log actually goes to logcat. From experience with Xamarin you had to call the native android logging method in order to achieve it.

Comment: @MikkoKoivisto ah yep looks like Debug.LogWarning/Debug.LogError works, go figure haha